# Why is JSON returning values like this 2.2348142859517371e-314 and 6.9531204333502763e-310

Tags: arrays, json, swift, url

Not returning parsed json, even though it prints.

```
guard let unwrappedZipcode = self.zipCode else {print("did not unwrap zipcode"); return}
        self.coordinateStore.getUserCoordintes(zipcode: unwrappedZipcode, completion: { (coordinatesJson) in
            print("********************")
            print(coordinatesJson)
            print("does this work")
            print("*******************")
            print(self.coordinateStore.locationCoordinates.first)

        })
```

Here is the function that makes the network call and parses the JSON:

```
func getUserCoordintes (zipcode: String, completion:@escaping ([Coordinates]) -> ()){
    GoogleCoordinateAPIClient.getCoordinateInformation(zipCode: zipcode) { (googleAPICoordinatesJson) in

        guard let unwrappedJson
            = googleAPICoordinatesJson as? [String: Any] else {print("did not unwrap at the first level"); return}

        guard let secondLevelArray = unwrappedJson["results"] as? Array<Any> else {print("did not unwrap at the second level"); return}

        guard let firstElementFromArray = secondLevelArray[0] as? [String : Any] else {print("did not unwrap at the third level"); return}

        guard let geometryDictionary = firstElementFromArray["geometry"] as? [String: Any] else {print("did not unwrap at the fourth level"); return}

        guard let locationDictionary = geometryDictionary["location"] as? [String: Any] else {print("did not unwrap at the fifth level"); return}

        guard let locationLat = locationDictionary["lat"] as? Double else {print("did not unwrap latitude"); return}
        guard let locationLng = locationDictionary["lng"] as? Double else {print("did not unwrap longitude"); return}

        let coordinatesObject = Coordinates.init(latitude: locationLat, longitude: locationLng)

        self.locationCoordinates.append(coordinatesObject)

        print(self.locationCoordinates.count)

        print("*********************************")
        print(self.locationCoordinates.first?.latitude)
        print(self.locationCoordinates.first?.longitude)
        print("*********************************")
    }
    completion(self.locationCoordinates)
}
```

Prints out 1 and the coordinates but showing up as an empty array, with nothing in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an async call. You need to call your function's completion handler inside the completion block of the async call.

Move the line:

```
completion(self.locationCoordinates)
```

just after the `print` statements. As you have it now, your call to `completion(self.locationCoordinates)` is being made long before the async call is even started.